# Analyzing data from a pre/post study when ANCOVA isn't possible and the denominator may be zero when calculating change scores

Tags: ancova, pre-post-comparison, two-way

We have conducted an experiment on an animal model of a psychiatric disorder using a pre-treatment (PRE)/post-treatment (POST) design with two treatments resulting in 4 study groups (No treatment, treatment 1, treatment 2, treatment 1 + 2). The symptoms of the disorder are assessed using behavioral tests which yield both continuous and discrete (counts) ratio measurements. I am using R for analyzing the data from this experiment.

Ideally, I would use two-way ANCOVA to analyze treatment effects on these variables. However, this is not possible since for some reason our PRE results (the covariate) are not independent of the treatment groups. To my knowledge, this leaves me with the following options (ranked in their order of idealness, I believe):

1. Calculating change scores as (POST - PRE)/PRE and conducting two-way ANOVA
2. Calculating change scores as (POST - PRE) and conducting two-way ANOVA
3. Simply conducting two-way ANOVA on POST results.

The problem is that there are a lot of zeros in the PRE results, which leads R to return inf/-inf /NaN when calculating change scores as stated in option 1. I was wondering if there is any statistically acceptable workaround for this problem other than settling for option 2?

Furthermore, is it acceptable to use option 1 for some variables (e.g., when there are no zeros in PRE results of a variable) and option 2 for the rest?

Comment: Is this a randomised experiment (or is the correlation of pre with treatment a result of it being not?)? Why do you call it pre-post study when there seems to be a no treatment control group? Is analyzing POST an option with PRE a linear covariate (or perhaps log(POST+0.5) with log(PRE+0.5) as a linear covariate?)?

Comment: @Björn No, the subjects were not randomized which probably explains the significant differences in PRE results between groups. While I'm aware that no statistical method is perfect in this regard, I'm trying to find the best way to maximally "factor out" the differences in pre results, and focus on comparing differences in pre-post change between groups. As for our study design, we first need to induce the disorder in our animals, then perform the PRE test to get baseline results, then administer the treatments, after which we repeat the same tests as PRE to get POST results. (continued below)